# Application crash when change appDelegate variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My Application was crash when i update my AppDelegate varibale. Am i declare the object in wrong way or UIColor not eligible to passing like this?

In AppDelegate.h i declare UIColor Object:

```
UIColor *myColor;

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *myColor;

In my viewController i update the myColor when a button pressed.

-(IBAction) pressed:(id)sender{
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.myColor = [sender backgroundColor];
}
```

But the application was crash after i pressed several time the button to update myColor. Can any expert point out which part goes wrong?

Comment: Are you synthesize the property myColor.

Comment: where did the crash take place?   Check the stack trace in the debugger when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any warning at this line? `[sender backgroundColor];`

If so, Instead of using `[sender backgroundColor];`

use,

```
UIButton *but=(UIButton *)sender;
appDelegate.myColor=[but backgroundColor];
```

Comment: Or just rewrite the prototype of the method like this:  -(IBAction) pressed:(UIButton * senderButton;  This way, Interface Builder won't let you connect something else than a button, and no need for a cast, that is just hiding a warning, but not preventing the problem to occur.

Comment: THanks Kingo. But i trace the source of error alr. It is due somewhere of my application using the appDelegate.myColor while i attempt to update the value so causing the application crash.